# Sync Framework - Cannot update or delete Primary Key table. Only insert work

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm trying to sync the following two tables.

In destination db, ParentTable cannot be updated or deleted; however, ChildTable sync properly.

Am I missing something? Thank in advance!

[image]

```
DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription("Name");

scopeDesc.Tables.Add(SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("ParentTable", sqlSourceConn));
scopeDesc.Tables.Add(SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("ChildTable", sqlSourceConn));


var sqlSourceProv = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlSourceConn, scopeDesc);
sqlSourceProv.CommandTimeout = 3600;
if (!sqlSourceProv.ScopeExists("Name"))
   sqlSourceProv.Apply();

var sqlDestinationProv = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlDestinationConn, scopeDesc);
sqlDestinationProv.CommandTimeout = 3600;
if (!sqlDestinationProv.ScopeExists("Name"))
   sqlDestinationProv.Apply();

var destinationProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("Name", sqlDestinationConn);

var sourceProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("Name", sqlSourceConn);

destinationProvider.MemoryDataCacheSize = MemorySize;
sourceProvider.MemoryDataCacheSize = MemorySize;

destinationProvider.ApplicationTransactionSize = BatchSize;

SyncOrchestrator orch = new SyncOrchestrator();
orch.RemoteProvider = destinationProvider;
orch.LocalProvider = sourceProvider;
orch.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Upload;

SyncOperationStatistics stats = orch.Synchronize();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have an FK relationship, it must be raising an error during the conflict (cannot delete the parent with a child)... you can verify this by subscribing to the ApplyChangeFailedEvent. you can set conflict resolution to get over the the issue.

Comment: void destinationProvider_ApplyChangeFailed(object sender, DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e) { e.Conflict.Type }. I'm getting 'LocalUpdateRemoteUpdate' from e.Conflict.Type. I'm new to SF. How can I solve the problem? Thank!

Comment: that means the row was updated in both source and destination...you can set the Action property to a conflict resolution that you prefer... see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc761628.aspx

Comment: JuneT, Thank you for the answer! Is there anywhere I can set all actions to RetryWithForceWrite instead of setting in ApplyChangeFailed event?

Comment: that's the only place you can set it cause that's the only place you can get notified of a conflict and do something about it.